# MySQL UID system across a database network

Tags: mysql, hash, uid

I want to create unique identifiers for my employee's in my databases, this is to avoid duplication across the databases i.e. if employee Barbra is stored in DB1, I don't want her to be created again in DB2.

My initial thought was to use a hash (e.g. SHA-1) create from the employee telephone number.
That way the chance of collision is extremely low and values will be unique.

However I'm aware having such a long UID will cost additional resources for performing queries, such as SELECT, on the UID's due to the size of each UID, lack of sorted structure and datatype (VARCHAR).

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try a before-insert `trigger` with the `uuid()` function?

Comment: What is your structure that you have multiple employee tables or can't have a master that is copied/replicated to other databases?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are your employees going to be defined in ALL databases or, for instance, each department has its own database with its own employees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sha1` from birthday is a bad idea, people have same birthdays, you can get clashes regardless of potential collisions within the hashing algorithm itself. The range of input is limited (birthdays).

There are several options:

- each database can implement [auto_increment_offset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset)
- each database could implement compound primary key made of `(id, db_id)` where `db_id` is a numeric unique identifier of the database's location.
- you can use `UUID`, it appears that it's costly but it's too early to assume anything without the data set size and hardware that this is ran at. `UUID` quickly solves your problem. You can easily store an `UUID` into a `binary(16)` column which gives you fixed width and low space footprint (example: `select unhex(replace(uuid(), '-', ''))`.